Prestashop - How to regenerate url maps link on Sitemap cms page?
I have a problem, the map with links is no longer displayed on my website, and I don't know which module exactly takes care of this, or how to generate again all the links and categories on the Sitemap page?
Before it looks like in the attached image, and now the Sitemap page is empty.
 
Thank you!
enter image description here
I have try to reset the "Google Sitemap" addon, but without any result. I don't know which addon is responsible for creating the sitemap page again.

The page layout is defined in
controllers/front/SitemapController.php
/themes/your_theme/templates/cms/sitemap.tpl

Hi @ventura thank you for your answer, I have found this file but how I can to regenerate all categories links to show again the complete maps on the sitemaps page?
